# How does gnome-documents depends on libreoffice?

Tags: apt, 20.04, libreoffice, gnome-documents

I want to install gnome-documents on Ubuntu 20.04 desktop. It's a pretty bare installation and I'm taking care of what is being installed. When trying to get it through apt I see the long list of dependencies includes the whole libreoffice suite:

```
~$ sudo apt install gnome-documents
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dleyna-server gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-tracker-2.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gnome-online-miners
  grilo-plugins-0.3 grilo-plugins-0.3-base grilo-plugins-0.3-extra gstreamer1.0-gtk3 libabw-0.1-1 libboost-date-time1.71.0 libboost-filesystem1.71.0
  libboost-locale1.71.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2 libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1
  libdleyna-core-1.0-5 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data
  libfreehand-0.1-1 libgfbgraph-0.2-0 libgom-1.0-0 libgpgmepp6 libgrilo-0.3-0 libgsf-bin libjuh-java libjurt-java liblangtag-common liblangtag1
  liblibreofficekitgtk liblua5.2-0 liblua5.3-0 libmhash2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls liboauth0 libodfgen-0.1-1
  liborcus-0.15-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libquvi-0.9-0.9.3 libquvi-scripts-0.9 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc
  libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer libreofficekit-data librevenge-0.0-0 libridl-java libsuitesparseconfig5 libtotem-plparser-videosite
  libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoloader-java libvisio-0.1-1 libwpd-0.10-10
  libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libzapojit-0.0-0 lp-solve lua-bitop lua-expat lua-json lua-lpeg lua-socket python3-uno
  uno-libs-private unoconv ure
Suggested packages:
  gnome-books imagemagick raptor2-utils rasqal-utils librdf-storage-postgresql librdf-storage-mysql librdf-storage-sqlite librdf-storage-virtuoso
  redland-utils libreoffice-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad tango-icon-theme fonts-crosextra-caladea fonts-crosextra-carlito libreoffice-java-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dleyna-server gir1.2-evince-3.0 gir1.2-gdata-0.0 gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-tracker-2.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gnome-documents
  gnome-online-miners grilo-plugins-0.3 grilo-plugins-0.3-base grilo-plugins-0.3-extra gstreamer1.0-gtk3 libabw-0.1-1 libboost-date-time1.71.0
  libboost-filesystem1.71.0 libboost-locale1.71.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5 libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2
  libdleyna-connector-dbus-1.0-1 libdleyna-core-1.0-5 libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libexttextcat-2.0-0
  libexttextcat-data libfreehand-0.1-1 libgfbgraph-0.2-0 libgom-1.0-0 libgpgmepp6 libgrilo-0.3-0 libgsf-bin libjuh-java libjurt-java liblangtag-common
  liblangtag1 liblibreofficekitgtk liblua5.2-0 liblua5.3-0 libmhash2 libmspub-0.1-1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libneon27-gnutls liboauth0
  libodfgen-0.1-1 liborcus-0.15-0 libpagemaker-0.0-0 libquvi-0.9-0.9.3 libquvi-scripts-0.9 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 libreoffice-base-core
  libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-impress libreoffice-math libreoffice-style-colibre
  libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer libreofficekit-data librevenge-0.0-0 libridl-java libsuitesparseconfig5 libtotem-plparser-videosite
  libuno-cppu3 libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 libuno-sal3 libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 libunoloader-java libvisio-0.1-1 libwpd-0.10-10
  libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.4-4 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libzapojit-0.0-0 lp-solve lua-bitop lua-expat lua-json lua-lpeg lua-socket python3-uno
  uno-libs-private unoconv ure
0 upgraded, 97 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 93,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 357 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
```

That's a weird dependency. When looking on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/gnome-documents) there is no such depedency and it's neither recursive according to `apt-rdepends`.

Can someone explain how the libreoffice suite is pulled with gnome-documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [package dependencies](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-documents).

The *gnome-documents* recommends installation of [*gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gir1.2-lokdocview-0.1) which depends on [*liblibreofficekitgtk*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/liblibreofficekitgtk).

You can decline the dependency by adding `--no-install-recommends` parameter:

```
sudo apt install gnome-documents --no-install-recommends
```

Comment: Great! My guess is that recommended packages' dependencies don't showup on apt-rdepends?

Comment: Seems to be true, it is dependency tree.